# How to migrate from custom ERP to Odoo,presrving previous data?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, erp

My company is currently using a custom made erp software.It lacks many features ad no more updates are available. So i thought of moving to Odoo which open and free. So how can i work odoo in existing setup. I need to preserve all my previous data and it should be accessible or visible in odoo also.

Help me with database problems that might arise.

Answer (score 1):

This question is probably too broad, but I'll describe what I did to migrate from LedgerSMB to OpenERP 6 back in the day.
OpenERP can import a CSV file for any of its models.  I ended up creating PostGresQL queries to export the LedgerSMB data in an OpenERP form with a lot of translations and case statements to produce CSV files that OpenERP would injest.  I ended up doing the chart of accounts by hand, and then wrapped all that in a custom module that I added.
The details will be very dependent on the structure of your existing ERP system, but the general approach of doing the transform in the export is reasonably likely to work.